# SessionState Timeout never fires

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-state

What am I doing wrong. The sessionState Timeout never fires,It only fires after 24 hours, I want to let it fire in 20 minutes on my webpage. In the web.config I handle the sessionstate like this:

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" mode="InProc"
    stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
    sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"
    timeout="1" stateNetworkTimeout="1"/>
```

timeout="1" is on purpose, for testing.
And in the code I check on which session I am by calling `Session.SessionID.ToString()`

Comment: Assuming `<sessionState timeout="20" />` does not work, are you sure you're not doing something like `Session.Timeout = 1440;` in your code?

Comment: the only session thing i'm calling is Session.SessionID.ToString()

Comment: Are you using FormsAuthentication as well?

Comment: no,     <authentication mode="Windows"/>

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `InProc`, you dont need `stateConnectionString`, `sqlConnectionString` and `stateNetworkTimeout`. Try removing these, and see if this works as you'd like.

Comment: hm, that exact web.config session block works here. do you have ajax with a timer by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

SessionState Timeout only fires when session state mode is InProc.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out that if I change cookieless=false -> true that it works , but now the sessionid is shown in my URL. How could I get rid of the sessionid in my url.
its like http://domain.com/(S(nvqmpm45j2fnnc21w00sjx55))/index.aspx