# Session state timeout parameter issue

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to set the timeout parameter of session state but it doesnt time out.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc"  timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

I am refreshing the page after 1 minute and I still the session state value.
Why?

Comment: Its sliding timer not absolute. How are you checking if the session is still alive?

Comment: I refresh the page after a minute

Comment: Did you change the session timeout in web site properties as well? I think the highest value overrides.

Comment: where is the session timeout in properties?

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing the page?? Are you checking SessionID or any loginPage??

Comment: try checking this at page load if(Session["UserLoginStatus"] == null)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SessionState Timeout never fires](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284673/sessionstate-timeout-never-fires)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way (if in case you are using FA as well)

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="1"/>
    </authentication>

    <sessionState timeout="1"  />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="1"/>
    </authentication>

    <sessionState timeout="1"  />
</system.web>
```

you welcome

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN says it shouldn't be lower then 4 minutes. Refer to the following it might help:

http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html

Comment: Can't see any MSDN link here which confirms this